# Extracting records from access database with

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, inner-join

I have done an application on VB.net with database access.
There are two tables, one with instruments records and the other with calibration records.
I want to loop through the instruments and for each instrument I just want to retrieve the last calibration record. There will be instruments with over ten records what become annoying for the user. 
Any suggestions?

My query code is as follows:

```
set rsDue = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsDue.ActiveConnection = MM_Transmille_STRING

rsDue.Source = "SELECT Calibrations.Cert_No, Calibrations.Cust_Ref, Calibrations.Rec_Date, Instruments.Inst_ID, Instruments.Description, Instruments.Model_no, Instruments.Manufacturer, Instruments.Serial_no, Instruments.Status, Instruments.Cust_Acc_No  FROM Instruments INNER JOIN Calibrations ON Instruments.Inst_ID = Calibrations.Inst_ID  WHERE Instruments.Cust_Name = '" & Session("MM_Username") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Session("MM_Password") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" + Replace(rsDue__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "' AND Instruments.Status IN ('N') ORDER BY Calibrations.Rec_Date DESC;" 


rsDue.CursorType = 0
rsDue.CursorLocation = 2
rsDue.LockType = 3
rsDue.Open()
rsDue_numRows = 0
```

Comment: you have this tagged Access-vba and VB.NET which is it?

Comment: You can certainly use the image tag and insert an image into your post; if not, then edit it rather than saying how it looks and not showing how it looks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `GROUP BY Instruments.Inst_ID`, you get only one result per instrument: the one with the latest Calibrations.Rec_date:

```
SELECT 
  Calibrations.Cert_No, 
  Calibrations.Cust_Ref, 
  Calibrations.Rec_Date, 
  Instruments.Inst_ID, 
  Instruments.Description, 
  Instruments.Model_no, 
  Instruments.Manufacturer, 
  Instruments.Serial_no, 
  Instruments.Status, 
  Instruments.Cust_Acc_No  
FROM 
  Instruments 
  INNER JOIN Calibrations ON Instruments.Inst_ID = Calibrations.Inst_ID  
WHERE 
  Instruments.Cust_Name = '" & Session("MM_Username") & "' 
  AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Session("MM_Password") & "' 
  AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Replace(rsDue__MMColParam, "'", "''") & "' 
  AND Instruments.Status IN ('N')
GROUP BY
  Instruments.Inst_ID  
ORDER BY 
  Calibrations.Rec_Date DESC
```

Comment: Hi Rik_S,Thanks a lot for the prompt answer. Somehow all I have is a 500 error when running that query. I can see the logic behind the  GROUP BY but still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should remove whitespacing I added for readability. Or doesn't that work? Also, did the query you provided work before (without 500 error)?

Comment: I removed the white space and made the query a string as soon as I copied from here.

Comment: Yes, Rik_S, the query works fine before the "GROUP BY" is added. Cheers

Comment: You might wanna look at your server logs to see what caused the 500-error then.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the update. I will have a look at the logs and get back to you. Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: This is the error that is being output:                   0x80040e21 - Microsoft JET Database Engine: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Cert_No' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: Any ideas would be great and much appreciated.

Comment: That error is thrown because you select more field then you are grouping by... This seems to be not supported by the database engine you're using. If you want to fix it, you could add all things you select in your GROUP BY, but i'm not sure if the query will work as intended then.

Are you sure it's MySQL by the way, and not MSSQL?

Comment: Hi Rik_S this worked (at least got rid of the 500 error and debug errors). I am doing some testing now to make sure the values aren’t repeating themselves. 
I will let you know the outcome :D

Comment: Hi Rik_S somehow it still displays more than one record by group.

Comment: That's what I thought. Since you group by everything now, it's not working as intended. If it were MySQL you were using (like your tag suggests) my solution should work. But other than that I can't really help you. Sorry :(

Comment: Hi Rik_S I appreciate all time you spent trying to find a answer. Thanks a lot. I will try and dig a solution in some other way.